# how many sites IIS 6 can handle

Tags: iis-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Is there a limit for creating Sites in IIS. i have searched and some forums have it in discussion which says there is no limit. Someone mentioned that he has created upto 100,000 sites in IIS 6 but i dont know his server specs though.

Personally i feel that whatever the limit of IIS, the resources will be run out well before the limit reaches.

how do big sites like blogger and wordpress handle a huge number of sites on their server.

Questions:

1) Is there an upper limit for IIS 6.0? if yes then what is it

2) What should be a good number of requests IIS should serve for a decent server? (I am not talking about dynamic requests on server or logs.)

3) Is there a way I can do the test run on my cloud to test the capability of my server. what factors should i keep in view. db request, page size, disk read/writes etc ?
Response shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's no sane limit to the number of sites, though Microsoft doesn't say the conclusion seems to be as many as the hardware can handle.  (Side Note: IIS7 can handle 100,000+)

1. Your concern should be on the hardware/bandwidth, you're doing to reach limits there way before IIS6 stops you from expanding.
2. Define "decent server", that's a pretty broad term, there are $2,000 servers and $200,000 servers, there are webfarms as well.  How many requests?  It's **highly variable**, it depends how lightweight your code is, how many database connections per page, etc, etc....there are **a lot** of factors.